# Laravel - Paginate and Append Search Result

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, pagination

This is probably has a very simple solution, but I have not been able to solve it. I need to paginate my search results, so when I go onto my next page, it does not reset my search results. Here is what I am trying to paginate:

```
$pets = DB:table('pets')
    ->where(function($q) use ($request){
        $q->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
})
->paginate(40)
```

The code posted above searches my database. I am able to paginate it using `paginate(40)` as shown above. The only thing is that the search resets when I go on to page two, for example. What I want is for the search to be applied to all the pages.

I tried using `appends()` with `$pets`, `$q` and `$request`, which none worked. I have also tried some answers from here, which yielded no results.

From the Laravel documentation I am guessing, your supposed to use `appends()` to apply the search to all the pages?

**EDIT:**

```
@foreach($pets as $pet)
 <p>{{$pet->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Pagination:

```
{{$pet->links()}}
```

AJAX Call:

```
$("#filter").change(function() {
$value=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{$pets->name}}",
    data: {'search':$value},
    success: function(data){
      $('#results').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: The problem is that on second page your `$request` does not hold the search term. Do you use GET or POST? (use GET and you will be OK).

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call this function ??

Comment: @Kyslik I use `GET` for the search.

Comment: And when you click on the 2nd page does the term stay in URL? Show us how you render pagination.

Comment: @Kyslik No it resets - that is the problem I am trying to fix. I render pagination using just the `paginate()` command. The `$pets` are `compact` into the page.

Comment: Alright edit your question with code where you use `$pets->render`... (from view)

Comment: Is this SPA? what do you want AJAX for?

Comment: @Kyslik - AJAX is used to get the results of the search instantly instead of have to re-load the page again. The problem is that the dataset returned can be very large. This is why I need to paginate results.

Answer (score 2):

In your view use something like this:

```
{!! $pets->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

or

```
{{ $pets->appends(\Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

Code above will create pagination links and add all parameters except `page` in it.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not yield any results. The search still resets when I go on to another page. I will try a few things myself right now.

Comment: I tried a few other things which did not work. Search still keeps resetting.

Comment: @spacetravel alright, you need to generate correct link at first; use Google Chrome and try to hover your mouse cursor above the link with page 2 in the left bottom corner you will see link is this link expected?

Comment: Looks to be correct - it adds a `?page=2`. I guess it is not adding the search query to the URL.

Comment: So request is empty, when you are on page 1 copy & paste URL after `?` (that means including search-term)

Comment: The URL goes like this: `?search=US&type=country`. Since its AJAX no URL gets displayed in the search-bar.

Comment: The base URL for search is `?search=US`.

Comment: @spacetravel So the search term for your example is `US`?